# How to create arbiter for scheduled tasks on diffrent server

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am looking for a good solution how to execute scheduled task on a one from few instances.

**The problem:**
I have a Java server with Spring Boot. Also I have a scheduled task that runs by using `@Scheduled(cron="...")` annotation. My application works with load balancer and usually it works on 3 instances. The scheduled task does update of postgres DB and scheduled task always runs on 3 server simultaneously.

How can I run the scheduled task only on one from servers ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select a leader somehow, selecting a leader can be quite hard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science). There are however quite a lot of solutions that can help in selecting a leader.

I personally like http://curator.apache.org/ a lot. However depending on the tools you already use, there might be already something that can provide the needed leader election support like Redis (https://redis.io/topics/distlock) or your database ([Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) -> Advisory Locks).

The simplest solution however, if you do not need failover capabilities, is to configure one app as your lead in a config file and do not execute the task when the config is not set.

Comment: I am considering case that one from instance can be stuck because of a hard operation execution, so in this case scheduled task must run on the second server instead of `leader`

Comment: Then you most likely need some sort of timeout, e.g. if there is no progress for n-minutes assume the process to be failed and schedule the work on another node. Then the other node could gather the lock and start processing. In addition you could document that work was done in a table. There are multiple posts about job queues with postgres on stackoverflow, just search for them.

Comment: I have done locking using distlock of Redis, thank you!